# Why do method definitions return symbols?

Tags: ruby

When you define a method, it returns a symbol with the same name as the method. Is there a point to this? Or is it just there as validation that you created it?

Like so:

```
def something
   ...
end
# => :something
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IRb *always* displays the result of calling `inspect` on the value of the last expression that was evaluated. It doesn't matter whether that expression is a literal expression, a conditional expression, a message send, a class definition expression or a method definition expression.

*Everything* returns a value in Ruby, i.e. *everything* is an expression, there is no such thing as a statement in Ruby.

In the past, the return value of a method definition expression was undefined. Most Ruby implementations simply returned `nil` from a method definition expression, but Rubinius for example returned the `CompiledMethod` object for the method that was defined.

With Ruby 2.1, [the return value of a method definition expression was standardized to be the `Symbol` corresponding to the method's name](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3753). This allows you to use the method definition expression as an argument in methods that expect the name of a method as an argument.

Some examples:

```
# Before Ruby 2.0:
def foo; end
private :foo

# After Ruby 2.0:
private def foo; end # similar for `protected`, `public`, `module_function`

# Before Ruby 2.0:
def map; end
alias_method :collect, :map

# After Ruby 2.0:
alias_method :collect, def map; end
```

On a personal note, I would have preferred a method definition expression to evaluate to an `UnboundMethod` object corresponding to that method, and methods like `public`, `private`, `protected`, `alias_method`, `module_function` etc. should be amended to accept `UnboundMethod`s in addition to `Symbol`s and `String`s.

Comment: I think it is 2.1, not 2.0.

Comment: I first agreed with your idea about `UnboundMethod` objects, but then, I thought about `attr_...` methods and the `alias` keyword, which are in a similar vein but cannot be designed to take `UnboundMethod` objects. If some of these methods take `UnboundMethod` objects and some take only symbols, it would be confusing. After all, it looks like symbols are the most robust way to refer to method names.

Comment: @JörgWMittag `alias_method` is in Ruby? :-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag Humm.. I thought it was in Rails..Thanks

Comment: Remember to update the versions in your example too. I suggest "< 2.1" and ">= 2.1" instead of before & after which are ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

The person who [proposed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3753) this had in mind a usage like this:

```
private def foo
  ...
end
protected def bar
  ...
end
```

Methods such as `public`, `private`, `protected` take symbols as arguments. The point was to make use of this syntax.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @Stefan I cannot find any in RDoc. They should write about this.

Comment: @sawa this syntax is not _beautiful_.. Earlier one was _beautiful_.. :-(

Comment: @sawa I meant [this syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Private)..

Comment: @sawa I am convinced.. My experience very little, so I was not aware of. Now I got convinced. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

All method defs return symbols in Ruby >=2.1 (not just the ones in IRB).

For example:

```
class Foo
  p def bar; end
end
# => prints :bar
```

Why is this interesting?

You may have noticed that there are many methods, particularly class-level methods, that take the symbolized name of another method as an argument. You may be familiar with `before_filter` in Rails controllers. Since method defs return symbols, you could potentially do this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter def my_filter
     # do stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: replacing `puts` with `p` prints `:bar`

Answer (score 0):

`IRB` respects the ruby standard “the result of last executed statement is returned from method.” Imagine the code:

```
def a
  def b
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

What is the result of execution this code? It follows:

```
a
# => :b
a.class
# => Symbol < Object
```

That said, IRB executes the method definition and returns/prints out it’s result. Which is, apparently, a `Symbol` instance.