# creating method on fly as a parameter while calling singleton method

Tags: ruby, macros

How's it possible in ruby ?

```
class Test
 # Creating singleton method
 def self.some_singleton_method(param1)
   puts param1 
 end
end

# calling singleton method by creating method on fly as a parameter to it
Test.some_singleton_method def method_name(some_param)
  # do something
end
## method_name
```

I've tried many places looking around, can't come up with an idea how's it's working.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to understand some code you have seen elsewhere or is this your attempt to solve a problem?

Comment: I'm trying to understand code that i've seen somewhere and i quickly realize that i didnt see the way i define above ever before.

Comment: Could you then please post the code you have seen (shortening it as necessary)? The code above isn't valid Ruby.

Comment: It's actually valid, if you delete all the comments.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, since [`def`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-def) is keyword, that creates new method in current scope, which is `Object` since you're calling it on the "top" level, i.e. not inside any class.  Starting from Ruby 2.1, [`def` returns method name as a symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215870/why-do-method-definitions-return-symbols), so your code is actually equivalent to

```
name = def method_name(some_param)
 // do something
end

Test.some_singleton_method(name) # outputs "method_name"
```

EDIT: Thanks to [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) for clarification that `def` is actually a keyword and not a method.

Comment: `def` is a keyword, not a method, so the conclusion of your first sentence does not follow (notwithstanding "kinda").  `saved_name = def method_name(some_param) end
 #=> :method_name; method(:method_name).owner
 #=> Object`, so you are passing the symbol for `Object#method_name` to `Test#some_singleton_method`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to do that.

**#1**

```
class Test
  def self.doit(m)
    send(m) yield
  end
end

Test.doit(:hello) do
  puts 'hi'
end
  #=> :hello
Test.new.hello
  #=> "hi"`.
```

**#2**

```
class Test
  def self.doit(str)
    eval(str)
  end
end

Test.doit "def hello; puts 'hi'; end"
  #=> :hello
Test.new.hello
  #=> "hi"`.
```